# iSQL Query Returning Value Multiple Times

Tags: sql, sybase, isql

The output of my column "SettlementsPayable" is returning the value for each line item even though that is not my desired result. It should only be returning the value when the ratecode = SHUNTING
Maybe it is how I am getting the data into my statement? I've included a screen shot of my data results in iSQL

```
     SELECT      ds_id AS TMP, ds_ship_date AS ShipDate, ds_ref1_text AS ContainerNumber,  

        (CASE ds_status WHEN 'A' THEN 'TEMPLATE'  

WHEN 'C' THEN 'CANCELLED'  

WHEN 'D' THEN 'DECLINED'    

WHEN 'E' THEN 'QUOTED'  

WHEN 'F' THEN 'OFFERED'   

WHEN 'H' THEN 'PENDING'  

WHEN 'K' THEN 'OPEN'  

WHEN 'N' THEN 'AUTHORIZED'  

WHEN 'Q' THEN 'AUDIT REQUIRED'  

WHEN 'T' THEN 'AUDITED'  

WHEN 'W' THEN 'BILLED'   

END) AS 'TMPStatus',  

        b.co_name as "BillTo", o.co_name AS Origin, o.co_city AS OriginCity, o.co_state AS 
OriginState,  

        de_arrdate AS DeliveryDate, de_arrtime AS ArrivalTime, de_deptime AS DepartureTime,    

        dba.disp_items.di_qty AS QTY, dba.disp_items.ratecodename AS RateCode, 
dba.disp_items.di_our_rate AS OURRATE, dba.disp_items.di_our_itemamt AS ITEMAMT, 
dba.disp_items.amounttype AS AMTTYPE, dba.disp_items.di_pay_itemamt AS CarrierPayables,  

( select sum ( amount ) from dba.amountowed where DBA.AmountOwed.Description = 'SHUNTING' and 
string ( ds_id ) = amountowed.shipment ) AS SettlementsPayable,  

        CASE ds_ship_type   

                WHEN '2201' THEN 'MONTREAL'   

                WHEN '2202' THEN 'DRYVAN'   

                WHEN '2203' THEN 'BROKERAGE'   

                WHEN '2204' THEN 'OLD BROKERAGE'   

                WHEN '2205' THEN 'LIFTING'   

                WHEN '2206' THEN 'WAREHOUSE'  
        END   

        AS Division  

FROM        dba.disp_ship   

JOIN        dba.disp_events ON de_shipment_id = ds_id   

JOIN        dba.disp_items ON dba.disp_items.di_shipment_id = dba.disp_ship.ds_id 

JOIN        dba.companies o ON o.co_id = ds_origin_id    

JOIN        dba.companies b on b.co_id = ds_billto_id   

WHERE       de_site = ds_findest_id   

AND de_event_type IN ('D','R','N')

and ds_id = '82261'

GROUP BY TMP, SHIPDATE, CONTAINERNUMBER, TMPSTATUS, BILLTO, ORIGIN, ORIGINCITY, ORIGINSTATE, 
DELIVERYDATE, ARRIVALTIME, DEPARTURETIME, QTY, RATECODE, OURRATE, ITEMAMT, AMTTYPE, 
CARRIERPAYABLES, SETTLEMENTSPAYABLE, DIVISION 

ORDER BY SETTLEMENTSPAYABLE DESC
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I assume table `disp_items` contains line items (please posrt all info don't make us assume). To solve the problem, don't join to this table. This may cause other problems (like missing fields), but that is the next thing to solve. Please edit your query and alias _every_ table and column (i.e. event_type) because we can't work out where these columns are coming from.

Comment: I'm guessing for example that `dba.disp_items.di_qty` is a line item figure. Normally for example you would aggregate this up by using `SUM(dba.disp_items.di_qty)`. Then rather then seeing individual quantities on each line item, you see the total

Comment: Please replace the image with the text from the (wrong) result set; also update the question with the (correct) expected result set; please also confirm which Sybase RDBMS product you're using (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery has a `where` clause that looks for rows with `DBA.AmountOwed.Description = 'SHUNTING'` ...

```
( select sum ( amount ) from dba.amountowed where DBA.AmountOwed.Description = 'SHUNTING' and
string ( ds_id ) = amountowed.shipment ) AS SettlementsPayable,
```

... but I don't see any place in the parent query where you limit the results to just rows with `SHUNTING` (this is supported by the image showing `RateCode` values of `PORT`, `RATES` or `SHUNTING`) so I'm guessing what you really want to see is a value under the `SettlementsPayable` column that is conditioned on the value in the `RateCode` column.

Assumptions:

- `SettlementsPayable` should show `sum(result)` if the parent row has `RateCode = 'SHUNTING'` otherwise show `0.00` (when `RateCode != 'SHUNTING'`)
- the current `SettlementsPayable` value of `10.00` is the *correct* value for the `RateCode = 'SHUNTING'` row (ie, there are no logic issues with the current subquery)
- `string()` is not a valid (system supplied) function in `Sybase ASE` so I'm guessing OP is using `Sybase SQLAnywhere` or `Sybase IQ`; in turn I think I've got the right syntax for the `SQLAnywhere/IQ` version of the `case` statement

One idea using a `case` statement:

```
select ... snip ...
       dba.disp_items.ratecodename AS RateCode,             # no change here, just displaying so we know where 'RateCode' comes from
       ... snip ...

       case when dba.disp_items.ratecodename != 'SHUNTING' then 0.00

            else (select sum(amount) 
                  from   dba.amountowed
                  where  DBA.AmountOwed.Description = 'SHUNTING'
                  and    string(ds_id) = amountowed.shipment)

       end case AS SettlementsPayable, 

       ... snip ...
from   ... snip ...
```

Comment: Hi and Thank you! Your post really helped me understand the issues with the query and the structure. Sorry, but I still have lots to learn. I have one more question regarding my current scenario. Let's say if I have a few different ratecodename that I want to include and not just 'SHUNTIN', how can I include more in the case statement?

Comment: For example here... I want to be able to add a few more ratecode's in with their amount.                                                                                                           
 case when dba.disp_items.ratecodename = 'SHUNTING' then 10.00

else (select sum (amount) from dba.amountowed where string ( ds_id ) = amountowed.shipment and dba.amountowed.startdate between '20220101' and '20221231') end case AS Total_Payable,

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, and assuming you're not familiar with the `case` statement I'd suggest you review the [syntax for the case statement](https://help.sap.com/viewer/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/17.0.01/en-US/3be45efb6c5f1014bd8df5da41b23288.html), see if you can modify your code accordingly, and if you still have problems then ask a new question, making sure to provide a (small) query that represents your coding attempt (along with wrong and expected outputs)